# Deploying public Django project through Heroku Github pipeline without making credentials public

Tags: django, github, heroku, deployment

I have a Django project in a public repo. It is separately deployed on Heroku, I want to enable the github Heroku pipeline feature. However this will require me to put my credentials in the settings.py which will be available in the public repo. I have integrations like `social-auth-app-django`, `django-storages` which require secret keys.

I found one [blog](http://fearofcode.github.io/blog/2013/01/15/how-to-scrub-sensitive-information-from-django-settings-dot-py-files/) which talks of putting only the credentials in a separate secret file but it won't work with the Heroku pipeline.

Is there any way/tools to resolve this without actually making the repo private ?

Comment: Your credentials should be in environment variables which you set via `heroku config`. See [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: yes this might be the only way, thanks.